# Couldn't import Django when moving whole virtualenv from windows to mac

Tags: django, virtualenv

It worked fine between windows OS but not in the mac. I didn't have requirements.txt file but was hoping the virtual environment with a lot of libraries imported by two developers would work just fine.

runserver generates error couldnt import django. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualenvs sometimes include binaries and sometimes need to be created with flags so they can be moved. What I'd recommend:

- Activate the virtualenv on the machine you have it working on
- Run the command `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
- Commit `requirements.txt` to version control
- Pull it down on the target machine
- Make a fresh virtualenv
- `pip install -r requirements.txt`

The `pip freeze` command will also include dependencies installed, so you may want to clean it up, but that should give you a working version. Good luck!